# SQL Duplicate Count if Customer has Spent on Specific Date and Returned?

Tags: mysql, count, duplicates

I've spent a fair amount of time trying to get my head round how to do this, and I can't. I'm making it far to complicated for myself, I understand the code, just not how it all flows together.

If I have table `"Customers"` with columns for `"customer_id"`, `"store_id"`, `"visited"`, and `"date"` - I want to identify Customers who visited (`visited = yes`) a specific store (`store_id="NEA"`) on a set date `"2015-05-14"` - and then have returned to the same store since then, and count the number of customers who have returned - can anyone help me out?

I know I would need to select `customer_id` for those who have a `store_id` of `"NEA"`, a date of "2015-05-14" and a "yes" for visited, but how do I then identify those who returned, and count them - so how many customers visited on that day and then returned?

So for example:

```
customer_id  |  store_id  |    date     |  visited

123              NEA        2015-05-14      yes

456              NEA        2015-05-14      yes

789              ABC        2015-05-16      no

123              NEA        2015-05-14      yes

654              TDF        2015-05-12      yes

987              PEH        2015-05-14      yes

123              NEA        2015-05-14      no

456              NEA        2015-05-17      yes

987              LEA        2015-05-14      yes

159              NEA        2015-05-16      yes

123              NEA        2015-05-19      yes
```

Comment: I updated my answer again, q.v. the third query.  I hope this is what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer_id, date
FROM Customers
WHERE visited = 'yes'
GROUP BY customer_id, store_id, date
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

**Follow the link below for a running demo:**

## SQLFiddle

The above query yields a list of duplicate customers and the dates on which they visited the same store twice or more.  If you want a count of duplicate customers by date, you can wrap it and subquery:

```
SELECT t.date, COUNT(*) AS duplicateCount
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT customer_id, date
    FROM Customers
    WHERE visited = 'yes'
    GROUP BY customer_id, store_id, date
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
) t
GROUP BY t.date
```

## SQLFiddle

**Update:**

Based on your feedback, the following query might be what you had in mind:

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer_id
FROM Customers
WHERE visited = 'yes'
GROUP BY customer_id, store_id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN date = '2015-05-14' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN date > '2015-05-14' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1
```

Comment: Thanks so far guys - that's helping a lot, but when I test it, it's not right. I want to know how many customers came in on 2015-05-14 (visited=yes, store_id=yes), and then came back - it's not pulling through the 456 customer? Am I missing something?

Comment: You should have shown us expected output so as to miminize guessing on our part.  So what output do you want?

Comment: I simply want customer_id  |  count of the duplicate customers - those who visited on 2015-05-14, and then came back.

Comment: Given your rep level, I will not answer further.  Please take one of my queries and try yourself, you will learn this way.

Comment: I'm trying. I really am. thanks for the help you've given me so far. I am appreciate. And I apologise for my lack of detail - this is all still pretty new for me

Comment: Update your question with _exact_ expected output.  And if you can't do that then you are not ready to ask the question yet.

Comment: In the `HAVING SUM()>=1 AND SUM()>=1`, the part before `AND` can be removed without changing the result?

Answer (score 0):

or something like this:

```
SELECT count(*) AS cnt,t.*
FROM yourTable AS t
WHERE
  `date` = '2015-05-14'
AND
  store_id = 'NEA'
AND
  visited = 'YES'
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING cnt >1;
```